# ng-Model value Usage in Other Directive in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having the data as below in my controller JS,

Here Subject and exam object is related by the code value in subject object, for example if subject name is "science " then code is "sci" and i try to save this "sci" in mg-model "myOptionSub" and i try to display the data related to "sci" in second dropdown based on model value "myOptionSub" and in div below. I am not able to use the ng-model value which is given by first dropdown in second dropdown.

```
    myApp.controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$location', function ($scope, $window, $location) {

    $scope.subject = {
        "subarray": [{
            'name': 'science',
            'code': 'sci'
        }, {
            'name': 'maths',
            'code': 'mat'
        }]
    };
    $scope.exam = {
        "sci": [{
            'name': 'science 1',
            'examcode': 's1'
        }, {
            'name': 'science 2',
            'examcode': 's2'
        }],
            "mat": [{
            'name': 'maths 1',
            'examcode': 'm1'
        }, {
            'name': 'maths 2',
            'examcode': 'm2'
        }]
    };
}]);
```

My HTML is

```
<select
    ng-model="myOptionSub"
    ng-options="subjectobj.code as subjectobj.name for subjectobj in subject.subarray">

</select>
<div>subject model: {{myOptionSub}}</div>
<div>subject model: {{exam.myOptionSub}}</div>

<select
    ng-model="myOptionExam"
    ng-options="examobj.examcode as examobj.name for examobj in exam.myOptionSub">

</select>


<div>exam model: {{myOptionExam}}</div>
```

Here i want to use the selected value of first dropdown (which is stored in model "myOptionSub") as a  filter to show the items in selected dropdown.

And My Doubt is in HTML where are the places and how i can use the model values in raw HTML and in any directives like ng-repeat as in my example.

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shmdhussain/uh5VU/#run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you looking for [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/PsYH6/1/)

by using ng-change you could have achieved it

```
 $scope.changesecond = function(){

    $scope.exam.myOptionSub = $scope.exam[$scope.myOptionSub];
    console.log($scope.examobj)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks For the help. This is what i am expecting but i am exploring how to use the model value of first dropdown in second dropdown's ng-options directive.

Comment: you could even try this http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/PsYH6/2/ without ng-change

Comment: I am getting one empty option for the first time, when is elect any option then only goes away. Could u pls help me in this?

Comment: do you want this http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/PsYH6/3/ ? second cannot be populated unless first is